# Difference between on touch down, up and move

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

As I am a little confused to know the meaning and difference between on_touch_down(),
on_touch_move(),
on_touch_up(). Can anyone explain me how these functions works?

**Note**: I have already read the documentation, still couldn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain correctly I will use the following example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class MyWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        print("on_touch_down")
        return super(MyWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        print("on_touch_move")
        return super(MyWidget, self).on_touch_move(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        print("on_touch_up")
        return super(MyWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

If we press with the mouse, then move it and then release it we get the following:

```
on_touch_down
on_touch_move
on_touch_move
on_touch_move
...
on_touch_move
on_touch_move
on_touch_move
on_touch_up
```

And this is precisely what is managed in these 3 events:

**on_touch_down:** It is called when the mouse is pressed for the first time.

**on_touch_move:** It is called while you move the mouse while holding down

**on_touch_up:** It is called when you release the mouse.